# Getting puppet to install modules

Tags: puppet

In my current setup I have a host-up script that takes a freshly provisioned VM in a DC somewhere, issues the couple commands that I need to run `puppet apply` (make sure hostname is set, that puppet is installed, that it can see it's puppet configuration).  Then `puppet apply` takes care of the rest (plus fabric to deploy our software).

All good, but installing needed puppet modules currently happens in my host-up script.  This works perfectly until I want to install new modules, and then I have to sort this by hand on existing hosts.  It seems that puppet should be able to do this, but I haven't found the right directive.

```
# If only this worked...
module { 'maestrodev-rvm':
    ensure => present
}
```

I've seen [puppet librarian](http://librarian-puppet.com/), but it appears to add more complexity than it solves for the small-ish number of modules we install.  Seems like a solution for later if/when we need something more complex.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`librarian-puppet` is the easiest answer to this. Personally I would always advise doing the leg-work ahead of time and implementing a solution that is scalable first, rather than constantly revising your approach.

It works on the same principle as `bundler` does for Ruby gems - you just create a `Puppetfile` which lists the modules *you* want (i.e. without dependencies).

When you run `librarian-puppet install` for the first time on your Puppet development machine (usually your local workstation), it will interrogate all modules and build a dependency list automatically (if the modules in question use the `metadata.json` file to detail dependencies). It will also create `Puppetfile.lock` to record the exact versions picked for each module and its dependencies.

For subsequent changes, you can run `librarian-puppet update <module>` to update a specific module to the latest version. This will re-compute dependencies and update `Puppetfile.lock`.

An important note - `librarian-puppet` will take *full* contrrol of your `modules` directory, so any custom modules you have written will need to be pulled out and referenced as modules in their own right within your `Puppetfile`.

Deploying is as simple as running `librarian-puppet install` on your nodes - this will look at the `Puppetfile.lock` (not the `Puppetfile`) and installs all of your modules.

Comment: `r10K` / Code Management are also good answers to this question.